# Ten Tec Argo IV wont connect to Fldigi on R Pi

Tags: linux, computer-control, fldigi

Cannot connect to Raspberry Pi with Fldigi, ttyusb0 does not show up in any cat control functions. I can connect my TS590S to the Pi and I can connect the Ten Tec to any window machine. But I cannot connect the Pi to the Ten Tec,any ideas as to a solution??

Thank you,

John

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t see ttyusb0 when you plug the radio into a Linux machine, but the COM port appears when you plug it into a Windows machine, then it sounds like you need to find a Linux driver for the USB-to-serial chipset inside the radio.

This means finding out which chipset it uses, then trying to find a driver for that chipset. You can use `lsusb` to find the chipset’s IDs, and then use those to search for a driver.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the reply I will look when I get back in a couple of days.